# Scala - Pivot sequence of Tuples to table form

Tags: scala

I have a Sequence of tuples, which could very well be a List of Lists generated by grouping  a set of records e.g.

```
[
    ["2017-01","Banking",25000000],
    ["2017-02","Banking",10000000],
    ["2017-02","Telecoms",12500000],
    ["2017-03","FCMG",22500000],
    ["2017-04","FCMG 2",17500000],
    ["2017-05","FCMG 2",5000000]
]
```

This was generated by grouping some records by a formatted date, a sector and taking the sum of some values. I will like to display this value in a matrix style as follows:

```
         | 2017-01 | 2017-02 | 2017-03 | 2017-04 | 2017-05 |
------------------------------------------------------------
Banking  | 25000000|10000000 | 0       | 0       | 0
------------------------------------------------------------
Telecoms | 0       |12500000 | 0       | 0       | 0
------------------------------------------------------------
FCMG     | 0       | 0       |22500000 | 0       | 0
------------------------------------------------------------
FCMG 2   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 17500000| 5000000
------------------------------------------------------------
```

To achieve that, I'm thinking I'll convert the first data structure to the form below:

```
[
    ["Banking", 25000000, 10000000, 0, 0, 0]
    ["Telecoms", 0, 12500000, 0, 0, 0],
    ["FCMG", 0, 0, 22500000, 0, 0],
    ["FCMG 2",0, 0, 0, 17500000, 5000000]
]
```

How can I achieve this where each of the 5 numbers after the sectors represent the corresponding values for each date and 0 where there is no corresponding value. 
Or Maybe

```
[
    {"Banking" -> (25000000, 10000000, 0, 0, 0)}
    {"Telecoms" -> (0, 12500000, 0, 0, 0)},
    {"FCMG" -> (0, 0, 22500000, 0, 0)},
    {"FCMG 2" -> (0, 0, 0, 17500000, 5000000)}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot the data with the following steps:

1. Create a sorted list of distinct `yearMonths`
2. Create a map of tuples with the `industres` as keys
3. Use `foldLeft` to expand the map values into separate lists of yearmonth columns
   by `industries`
4. Use `reduce` and `zip` to sum the lists element-wise by `industries`

Here's an example:

```
val data = Seq(
  ("2017-01","Banking",25000000),
  ("2017-02","Banking",10000000),
  ("2017-02","Telecoms",12500000),
  ("2017-03","FCMG",22500000),
  ("2017-04","FCMG 2",17500000),
  ("2017-05","FCMG 2",5000000)
)

val yearMonths = data.map(_._1).distinct.sorted
// yearMonths: Seq[String] = List(2017-01, 2017-02, 2017-03, 2017-04, 2017-05)

val pivotedMap = data.groupBy(_._2).mapValues( _.map( x =>
  yearMonths.foldLeft( Seq[Int]() )( (list, ym) =>
    if (ym == x._1) list :+ x._3 else list :+ 0
  )
)).mapValues( _.reduce(
  (a, e) => (a, e).zipped.map(_ + _)
))

// pivotedMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[Int]] = Map(
//   Telecoms -> List(0, 12500000, 0, 0, 0),
//   Banking -> List(25000000, 10000000, 0, 0, 0),
//   FCMG -> List(0, 0, 22500000, 0, 0),
//   FCMG 2 -> List(0, 0, 0, 17500000, 5000000)
// )
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a foldLeft in there somewhere :)